# Appengine ndb: differentiating between creating and editing?

Tags: python, entity-framework, google-app-engine

I have the following code in models.py:

```
class Order(ndb.Model):
  created_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  due_dates = ndb.DateProperty(repeated=True)

class Task(ndb.Model):
  created_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

  order = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)
  order_updated_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
  ...
```

When an order is created, 6 tasks will be created. Currently, I have the following method:

```
  def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    # Deleting old tasks
    tbd = Task.query(Task.order == self.key).fetch(keys_only=True)
    ndb.delete_multi(tbd)

    # Generating new tasks
    for entry in self.entries:
      pt = entry.producetype.get()
      # Now create Tasks and store them into the database
      Task(order=self.key,
           order_updated_at=self.updated_at,
           order_entry_serial=entry.serial,
           date=dt_sowing,
           action=TaskAction.SOWING).put()
```

Now I am changing the way Order and Task are created. 
**I want to create Tasks when an Order is created AND I want to delete the tasks of an Order when an order is modified**

Unfortunately, ndb's API states:

> The Datastore API does not distinguish between creating a new entity
>   and updating an existing one. If the object's key represents an entity
>   that already exists, the put() method overwrites the existing entity.
>   You can use a transaction to test whether an entity with a given key
>   exists before creating one. See also the Model.get_or_insert() method.

I don't really understand how Model.get_or_insert can be applied in my scenario.
Note that I can't use `_pre_put_hooks` because my Tasks needs to reference their Order via its key.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore `get_or_insert()`, it return an entity in any case and don't help you. You need to check if tasks exist in the datastore. I think to wrap a `get()` or a `get_multi()` function in a `try/except`. If the entities exists, delete it else create 6 new Task entities with a `put_multi()`.

**edit**: you need timestamps for check the preexistance. Look [datetime property](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time) and auto_now_add/auto_now options.

Comment: where do I put the `get()` call? Do I put it in `pre_put_hook`? If so, how do I assign Order.key to the new Tasks? 

If I put it in post_put_hook, then wouldn't the key always exist?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand. However, get_or_insert() don't help and you need timestamps for check the preexistance. Look [datetime](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time) property and auto_now_add/auto_now options